# How to use 'MapControllers' in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

See
[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

This doc page can be switched to 2.1. It shows attribute routing instructions.

But, methods like `app.UseEndpoints(()=>)`, `endpoints.MapControllers();` or `app.MapControllers();` don't exist in my environment.

I've installed these packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions
```

What else should I install?

Answer (score 2):

> But, methods like app.UseEndpoints(()=>), endpoints.MapControllers();
> or app.MapControllers(); don't exist in my environment.

This is a documentation issue, **the Endpoint routing applies to ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later, instead of Asp.net Core 2.1**.

In Asp.net core 2.1 MVC application, you should use the `UseMvc` middleware and the `MapRoute()` method, the startup.cs file like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to use the Endpoint routing, you could migrate the application from Asp.net core 2.1 to Asp.net core 3.1. Refer to [this link and steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

For the documentation issue, you can submit a feedback by click the button at the end of the document:

[image]